# Calculating the efficiency of an algorithm

Tags: multithreading, performance

I finished parallelizing an algorithm using multithreading and I need to calculate its efficiency (already got the speed up factor). So I'm using the formula **E = old execution time/ (new exec time * number of processors)**. So the question is what should I put as the number of processors, 1 or the number of cores, or the number of threads?

```
Average 1 = 519.6818ms
Average 2 = 172.7764ms
Speed Up Factor = 519.6818/172.7764 = 3.0078286155
Efficiency = Speed Up factor * 1/number of procs(??)
```

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is what should I put as the number of processors, 1 or the number of cores, or the number of threads?

Efficiency is "the ratio of the useful work performed to the total resources expended". To determine efficiency, you'd need to know 2 things that you don't have (amount of useful work done and energy consumed) and the things you do have (time taken and number of threads/CPUs/cores) aren't needed.

What you are calculating is a scalability ratio. These are used to assess how well software can scale to more CPUs (and to answer questions like "If I buy a computer with twice as many CPUs, how much will it help performance").

For this purpose; you should ensure that the number of threads is less than or equal to the number of cores; and then use the number of threads.

Note that for a better idea of scalability you can plot it on a graph (e.g. with "time/number of cores" on the Y axis and "number of cores" on the X axis).

To understand how a graph can be very important; imagine a scenario like "there are N stages, each stage has a mutex and takes about the same amount of time, and each thread repeatedly does stages in order (e.g. stages 1 to N, then stages 1 to N again, then stages 1 to N again, ...)". In this case you'd expect good scalability up to N threads (because the mutexes tend to cause the threads to become synchronised in a "one thread per stage" way), and for more than N threads there's almost no scalability because "more threads" just means more threads waiting to acquire a mutex. In other words, there'd be a scalability cut-off, and a single number won't tell you where that scalability cut-off is.